# Re-applying filter to filtered JTable view

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, rowfilter

I have a JTable with filtering options added to each column header, using the SwingBits java library. Now in addition to the column header filters, I filter my last column by text entered in a JTextField.

The problem is, once I filter the jtable using the column filters, and I try to use the TextField filter, the filtering is applied to the original table and not the filtered view. I understand the table model contains the original table data, so is there a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an "andFilter" to combine multiple filters into one.

For example take a look at the section of the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). You can modify the demo with code like the following to filter rows where the text is found in two columns, not just one:

```
//rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 1);
List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 0));
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 1));
rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
```

Comment: Its not as straight forward in my case. Because I use SwingBits (which is an external library) for my column header filtering, it has it's own filtering mechanism which I still don't quite understand after studying the source code. I have no clue on how to integrate that with my payload filter.